# Using Stripe CLI correctly in docker

Tags: docker, stripe-payments

I would like to use Stripe CLI in docker. I have to mention that I am new to docker.  I have loaded stripe/stripe-cli from dockerHub.

`docker run --rm -it stripe/stripe-cli:latest`.

`docker image ls` also shows me that the image is available locally. But `docker ps` does not show me a stripe CLI container? Is this right or wrong?

When I run
`docker run -it stripe/stripe-cli login`

I have to authenticate with Stripe in the browser. This is the output:

```
Your pairing code is: xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxx
This pairing code verifies your authentication with Stripe.
To authenticate with Stripe, please go to: https://dashboard.stripe.com/stripecli/confirm_auth?t=5ifDAxXxXxXxXxX
⣾ Waiting for confirmation... > Done! The Stripe CLI is configured for Mike's Test Stripe with account id add1_xxx

Please note: this key will expire after 90 days, at which point you'll need to re-authenticate.
```

My que
I do that successfully but I still can't use stripe-cli afterwards? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried either of the suggestions in this GH issue? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/issues/497#issuecomment-686558554

Comment: @NickODell Thanks! Now it works!

Comment: For future people who find this, which solution worked?

Comment: I use: docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/sh -it stripe/stripe-cli:latest then stripe login to authenticate and you are inside the container. at this moment the container is running and displays under docker ps. Small Note: Container name: "sad bratta"

Answer (score 14):

I think there should be a docker compose solution too here. This is my working setup:

**Framework:** Django 4

**Python**: 3.9

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  stripe-cli:
    image: stripe/stripe-cli
    container_name: stripe-cli
    command: "listen --api-key ${STRIPE_API_KEY} --device-name ${STRIPE_DEVICE_NAME} --forward-to web:8000/payment/webhook/"
    env_file:
      - stripe_cli.env
  
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Contents of .env file (remember this should stay locally on the machine. Dont commit this file. create it locally)

```
STRIPE_API_KEY = rk_test_somelongkey***************
STRIPE_DEVICE_NAME = Name
```

**Please note a few things:**

In "web:8000", 'web' is service name of the django project

Comment: Because docker compose has interpolation (https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#interpolation), I had to add a second `$` (e.g. `$${STRIPE_API_KEY}`)

Answer (score 4):

To retain configuration you need to use bind mounts (`-v` attribute).
On https://stripe.com/docs/cli/login you can see that configuration is stored inside `.config/stripe/config.toml` so we can mount `~/.config/stripe` from our local disk

```
docker run --rm -v ~/.config/stripe:/root/.config/stripe -it stripe/stripe-cli:latest login

Your pairing code is: asd-asd
This pairing code verifies your authentication with Stripe.
To authenticate with Stripe, please go to: https://dashboard.stripe.com/stripecli/confirm_auth?t=asdasdasdasd
⢿ Waiting for confirmation... > Done! The Stripe CLI is configured for asd with account id acct_asd

Please note: this key will expire after 90 days, at which point you'll need to re-authenticate.
```

so now we can repeat without need to log in again

```
docker run --rm -v ~/.config/stripe:/root/.config/stripe -it stripe/stripe-cli:latest customers list
```

Comment: That works with Shopify as well, and some others that use CLI

Answer (score 4):

If your purpose is simply testing your webhooks do what [their documentation says](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/docker):

> Since Docker containers are ephemeral, stripe-cli login cannot be used without defining a data volume. You can use the --api-key flag instead.

```
docker run --rm -it stripe/stripe-cli:latest listen --api-key sk_test_XXXXXX --forward-to localhost/stripe_hook
```

Comment: If you want to follow the Stripe docs but also don't want to have to type all of this every time, I've created a simple bash script/environment to simplify the command. https://github.com/joshmakar/stipe-cli-docker-bash

Answer (score 0):

`docker run`'s `--rm` option indicates that the container will be removed after it exits.
And commands do exit unless it listens to something e.g. `listen`.

Note that the default `entrypoint` of this docker image is `/bin/stripe`; that is, it expects one of the stripe cli command.

e.g. `docker run --rm stripe/stripe-cli:latest customers list`
(as in `stripe customers list` otherwise)

Looking at the way its `Dockerfile` is written, I suppose it's intended to be used as one-off command execution as opposed to bash-kind of interactive platform.

A simple solution seems to be the use of [`STRIPE_API_KEY` or `--api-key` option](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/docker). Set this env var and you're good to go for any command, even without `login`.